# Window form refresh parameter passing

Tags: vb.net

I currently testing with visual studio window form with Vb.net

I want to refresh my user login and pass the parameter to other form. but every time I success login in first user, when i relog to another user. it remain same data as first user

```
Private authUser As custMain = New custMain()
Dim id As String
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If sql.HasConnection Then

        If isAuthenticated() = True Then

            sql.RunQuery("select UID from userAccount where username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' and password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' and userType='cust'")
            For Each i As Object In sql.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
                id = i.item("UID")
            Next
            authUser.AuthName = id
            authUser.Invalidate()
            authUser.Refresh()
            authUser.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

```
Private authUser As custMain 
Dim id As String
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If sql.HasConnection Then

        If isAuthenticated() = True Then

            sql.RunQuery("select UID from userAccount where username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' and password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' and userType='cust'")
            For Each i As Object In sql.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows
                id = i.item("UID")
            Next
            authUser = New custMain()
            authUser.AuthName = id
            authUser.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```